# Dynamic and Automatic approvers in SPD workflow (OOB)

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, approval-process, out-of-the-box

I have a list items that need to be approved by a set of approvers. The list of approvers would change based on department, location and value of item.
For example, if there an item to be moved from Dept A, it has to be approved by Dept A's manager and if it is from Dept B, it should Dept B. Next approver would depend on the Business unit they belong to. Finally it comes to Taxation team to check for compliance and then approved.
Any help or pointers on how to achieve this using only OOB features ?

Appreciate your help....

Comment: Can you use workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that deeply nested my be difficult to pull from the imported user profiles in AD within a Sharepoint workflow, but a workflow is still the best option in my opinion. It just requires a little setup.

I would create a secondary user list that defines the user (person/group), the department (choice), business unit (choice), manager (person/group).  Then when an item is submitted, you look up to this list where the creator is equal to the user and find their manager.

You could also include the taxation folks into the mix of that list too so it is fully dynamic, or they could be hard coded into your workflow.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I was also thinking something similar but confused. Your suggestion throws some more light. Will try and post the final solution, after we implement.